# Cloudera CDH4: Can't add a host to my cluster because canonical name is not consistent with hostname

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, cloudera

I am installing CDH4 on a 4-node cluster using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I am able to install cloudera manager and start a one-node cluster on the master machine. However, once I add a new host, CM says it has a bad health and throws the following error:

"The hostname and canonical name for this host are not consistent when checked from a Java process."

I modified the contents of /etc/hosts on the master and all the hosts to include the IP addresses followed by the FQDN of each machine. Do I also need to set-up a dns server to make this work?

Comment: Check [this](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/scm-users/xr0Yr5_Hilc) discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not necessarily set up a DNS server to get this to work, but forward and reverse DNS must match explicitly for Hadoop to function properly.

The Hadoop Operations book has a [good example](http://books.google.com/books?id=W5VWrrCOuQ8C&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=dns+hadoop+operations&source=bl&ots=PCgmOEcQ31&sig=ayxQ0bI6l4zYgFss7CfpbJtxj10&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QJ5uUtS4D5S84AOXioDIAg&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=dns%20hadoop%20operations&f=false) of how to write a simple Java program to validate your Forward + Reverse DNS are lined up.  Of course, you can instrument this program further to help you debug in the event that they are not aligned.

Should you have to address this, a combination of host entries, NIC configs, and/or records in a hosted name server will most likely be needed.

Answer (score 0):

i have a same problem and i fixed it by applying following things...

run this command to check fqdn of host

```
   python -c "import socket; print socket.getfqdn(); print socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())"
    ip-172-*-*-*.eu-central-1.compute.internal -> "this cause the issue"
    172.*.*.*
```

simply you could create the cname of host in route53 same like we creates the alias in hosts file in linux

```
172.*.*.* host1-production.com ip-172-*-*-*.eu-central-1.compute.internal
```

then restart the cloudera-scm agent service

***Note : In my case i used hosts file to resolve own ip address and i have set hosts: files dns in nsswitch.conf file . rest of host resolve by aws route53.***

best of luck guys